# iPhone + Stitching more than 2 different images using opencv

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, opencv

I have used below source code for stitching more than 2 different images using opencv.

Below code is works but i want to stitch more than 2 different images. Below code not working on different images.

[OpenCV Computer vision with iOS: stitching panoramas](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch)

Please provide me code for stitch more than 2 different images.

Comment: dont want to download/read that code... can you explain what it does?
In general you would stitch 2 images and then stitch a third image to that combined image with the same method. If that gives too many distortions you would want to use some kind of bundle adjustment.

Comment: did you figure it out @Sandeep Agrawal?